# FIrebaseUI( version 0.4.0): firebase recycler Adapter not fetching data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have this DataSaveActivty where I need to populate my data in recycler view, when I run this code it displays no error and no card just a blank activity with toasts. I couldn't find anything wrong but why isn't it displaying anything.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_save);
    mReceipt = new RecyclerView(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent == null) {
        keyValue = null;
    } else {
        //keyValue = intent.getExtras().getString("key");
        keyValue = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        Toast.makeText(DataSaveActivity.this, keyValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bills").child(keyValue);
    mRef.keepSynced(true);
     mReceipt = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.othersRecycler);
    mReceipt.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mReceipt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ReceiptViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ReceiptViewHolder>
            (DataModel.class, R.layout.reciept_row, ReceiptViewHolder.class, mRef){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ReceiptViewHolder viewHolder,DataModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setBillNo(model.getBillNo());
            viewHolder.setStoreName(model.getCompany());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.setBillTotal(model.getTotal());

        }
    };
    mReceipt.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
public static class ReceiptViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    public ReceiptViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setBillNo(String billNo){
        TextView BillNo = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptBillNo);
        BillNo.setText(billNo);
    }
    public void setStoreName(String company){
        TextView StoreName = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptStoreName);
        StoreName.setText(company);
    }
    public void setDate(String date){
        TextView Date = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptDate);
        Date.setText(date);
    }
    public void setTime(String time){
        TextView Time = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptTime);
        Time.setText(time);
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone){
        TextView Phone = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptPhone);
        Phone.setText(phone);
    }
    public void setBillTotal(String total){
        TextView BillTotal = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptTotal);
        BillTotal.setText(total);
    }

}
```

Data is present at child keyValue which is retrieved from another activity and then this data should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this:

```
mReceipt.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

so the data will appear in the page

check this:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/204

Comment: does the job but can you explain why?

Comment: check the link in the edit, this was a problem in the older versions where if you removed it, then it shows the data